# Open .pdf's inside chrome using SKIM

Tags: pdf, google-chrome, skim

The built in pdf `viewer` of `chrome` is rather nice, but I like (and more used to) `skim`. My ultimate goal would be to click on a `pdf` file and to have it opened in the tab (within `chrome`) using `skim` as the backbone.

I managed to disable the built in viewer (`chrome://plugins/`); then, clicking on a pdf simply downloads it, and I can open it with `skim`. This is cumbersome, and the file is saved locally on my `~/Downloads`. Is there a way to make it flow nicer? Is there a way to automatically open the file once downloaded (`skim` is my default viewer anyway)?

Answer (score 2):

If you download a pdf then click on the arrow on the downloaded file button at the bottom of the browser window and select "Always open files of this type", then pdf files will be automatically opened by the default application on download - in your case skim.

They will still be in the download folder however.

To undo this behaviour go into chrome advanced settings and under Download click "Clear auto-opening sett